# tableView.reloadData() causes crash in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8, xcode6

I read a question asked on Stackoverflow about making a view controller transparent so when it is shown the parent view controller can still be seen behind. I was able to do so:
[image]

However now when I click add subject the table view does not add the subject to my tableview like so (this is the view that appears behind the above view when the "+" button is tapped):
[image]

but if i exit to my main menu and come back to the table view it displays the list like so (which is what I want when I tap "Add Subject).

[image]

I think this is due to `tableView.reloadData()` being in my `ViewWillAppear` function.

With this in my mind i added `tableViewClass.tableView.reloadData` to the "Add Subject" button action in order to reload data as soon as the button is pressed however I get `fatal error: found nil while unwrapping optional value` and it highlights `tableViewClass.tableView.reloadData`

I know that the parent view controller (one with the table view) is not killed once the New Subject view controller appears in order to show it behind. This is why "ViewWillAppear" is never called.

Im still a little confused as to why its crashing though... here is my code for my button:

```
@IBAction func btnAddTask_Click(sender: UIButton){


        subMngr.addSubjectMonA(txtSubject.text, time1: txtTime.text, time2: txtTime2.text, col: monAview.ColorValue)
    self.view.endEditing(true)

    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var newCell = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("SubjectsEntity", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

    newCell.setValue(txtTime.text, forKey: "starttime")
    newCell.setValue(txtSubject.text , forKey: "title")
    newCell.setValue(txtTime2.text , forKey: "endtime")
    newCell.setValue(monAview.ColorValue, forKey: "color")
    context.save(nil)


    txtSubject.text = ""
    txtTime.text = ""
    txtTime2.text = ""

    MondayAClass.TableView.reloadData() // ERROR HERE

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)



    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

***EDIT***

Here is my code to present the view controller and make it transparent:

```
 @IBAction func addInfo(sender: AnyObject) {


    let story: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let monAadd = story.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MondayAadd") as MondayAadd
    monAadd.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    monAadd.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom // If this line is taken out everything works fine
    self.presentViewController(monAadd, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Comment: What is `MondayAClass`, and why does it have a property named `TableView`? Why aren't you using the `tableView` property on the `UITableViewController` instance?

Answer (score 0):

> fatal error: found nil while unwrapping optional value

This is Swift's way of saying that you attempted to access a `nil` value. Ensure that you have an owning relationship between the table view and its view controller, and this shouldn't happen.

Comment: Yeah I saw this on another post, it definitely does have an owning relationship. If I change my code to make the view controller not transparent then everything works fine.

Comment: I've added my code for making the view controller transparent to my question.